# How to create an array of Google Maps Geocoordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

In Javascript, I have two arrays, called latitude and longitude, that have appropriately long and lat values (as strings originally from an asp.net controller, I got them from parsing an XML feed).

What I want to do is create a new array, called points, that has the lat/lng values in it, so I can display those values on a map. Here is what I thought should work, but does absolutely nothing:

```
       var points=new Array();

       for(var i=0; i<latitude.length; i++){
       points=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i], longitude[i]);
       }
```

the latitude and longitude arrays are the same length, I don't think thats a problem. Thanks, Amanda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not *adding* elements to the array, but instead *assigning* a new `LatLng` object to the `points` variable in each loop iteration (`points = new`). To add elements to the array, either subscript the array position (`points[index] = value`) and assign the object to it:

```
var points=new Array();
for (var i=0; i < latitude.length; i++) {
  points[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i], longitude[i]);
}
```

Or use [`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var points = [];
for (var i=0; i < latitude.length; i++) {
  points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i], longitude[i]));
}
```

Comment: `bounds` are also handy https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: Ah, thanks, that was a rather silly error on my part, its working now!

Comment: @Amanda_Panda: You're welcome. Also consider SteveRobbins suggestion if you need to draw a *rectangle*.